# WebGL annotations not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am trying to render a 3D model using Three.js on the browser and also trying to add annotations similar to https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/interactive-test-778258c754a74d37a72d3274b80c6ce1 . I am using https://manu.ninja/webgl-three-js-annotations/ as a reference. I tried following the first half of the article which just adds the screen projections but i dont see any annotations in my model.Would really appreciate any help in understanding what i am missing.

HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cube</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0;}
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="annotation">
        <p><strong>Cube</strong></p>
        <p>Sentence about cube</p>
    </div>
    <canvas id="number" width="64" height="64"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/99/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r99/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="/examples/3d-obj-loader/scripts_annotation.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

scripts_annotation.js

```
//global variables
var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
var sprite, spriteBehindObject, model;


init();
render();

//camera set up and model loading
 function init(){
//camera settings
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 2, 2000 );
camera.position.set(700,500,1250);

scene = new THREE.Scene();

//renderer setting
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
// renderer.setClearColor(0x1E1E1E);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
renderer.gammaFactor = 2.2;
renderer.gammaOutput = true;
renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

window.addEventListener('resize',onWindowResize, false);

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
controls.enableZoom = true;



var urls = [ 'posx.jpg', 'negx.jpg', 'posy.jpg', 'negy.jpg', 'posz.jpg', 'negz.jpg' ];
var loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().setPath( '/examples/3d-obj-loader/reflections/Park2/' );
var background = loader.load( urls );

var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0xffffff , 5 );
light.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );
scene.add( light );

//model

// Mesh

const cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(500, 500, 500);

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    cubeGeometry,
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x156289,
        emissive: 0x072534,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        shading: THREE.FlatShading
    })
);

const line = new THREE.LineSegments(
    new THREE.WireframeGeometry(cubeGeometry),
    new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        linewidth: 1,
        opacity: 0.25,
        transparent: true
    })
);

scene.add(mesh);
scene.add(line);
}

function onWindowResize(){
   camera.aspect = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
   camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
   renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

 }

function render(){

requestAnimationFrame( render );
controls.update();
renderer.render(scene, camera);
updateScreenPosition();


}
function updateScreenPosition() {
  const vector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 17, 8);
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;

  vector.project(camera);

  vector.x = Math.round((0.5 + vector.x / 2) * (canvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio));
  vector.y = Math.round((0.5 - vector.y / 2) * (canvas.height / window.devicePixelRatio));

  const annotation = document.querySelector(".annotation");
  annotation.style.top = `${vector.y}px`;
  annotation.style.left = `${vector.x}px`;
  annotation.style.opacity = spriteBehindObject ? 0.25 : 1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should [show a working demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because it's hard to figure out what it could be. Your code example never assigns a value to `spriteBehindObject`, or the `.annotation` div could have CSS rules that don't let it move. Could be a number of things.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Please find a working demo here https://codepen.io/codepen_novide_coder/pen/YzwdxBe?editors=111

Comment: You should take a look at your developer console, it fires an error on each frame. Looks like the renderer is having a hard time rendering your `line` object. Simply comment out line 97: `// scene.add(line);` and you'll see your annotation working as expected. Then you'll have to figure out why the `line` object isn't behaving as expected.

Comment: I commented out line 97 in code pen and do see the annotation working as expected but when i try the same thing locally and try to render it on my browser i dont see any errors in the console and dont see the annotation working as expected here . Can you help me understand why i might be seeing something like this ?

Comment: No idea... my best guess is that different versions of Three.js behave differently. The one from the article uses `r85`, the one in your codepen uses `r99`, and who knows what revision your local computer is using :)

Comment: I tried changing the version on my local computer to r85 and i still don't see the expected annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by replacing the following line in html file on my local machine

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/examples/3d-obj-loader/Surface_style.scss" type="text/scss"> to <link rel="stylesheet" href="/examples/3d-obj-loader/Surface_style.scss" type="text/css">
```

This line was the only difference between the codepen and code on my local machine